# Airline policies on LON to CPH with excess baggage

Tags: air-travel, airlines, luggage, bicycles

A friend is flying to Denmark from New Zealand.  He's got the flight to London sorted, but from LON to Copenhagen he's wondering about excess baggage - as he'll have a bicycle + stuff in a box (about 15kg).

Air NZ to LON is only charging NZ$37.50 (about £20), but not sure who to go with for London to Copenhagen.  The flight is for early March, and so far British Airways is showing as the cheapest for just the flight.

Does anyone know what their policy is for excess baggage, and whether anyone else who flies LON to CPH might be cheaper (for excess baggage)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Which? consumer magazine BA would be the cheapest for baggage on that route.

According to the [baggage page](http://www.britishairways.com/travel/bagchk/public/en_gb) on ba.com:

If you wish to take more bags than your free checked baggage allowance, you can pay to check in up to 10 extra bags per person with the same weight restrictions as your free allowance.

[image]

Have a good read of the page for conditions etc.